# How to use Azure Data Factory Schedule property?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm trying to create an advanced schedule trigger, following this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-pipeline-execution-triggers#schedule-property

1. I Created a very simple pipeline:

   [image]
2. tried a manual run and it was OK:
   [image]
3. Created a schedule (each 1 minute) trigger
4. Opened the JSON for that trigger and modified it to:

```js
{
    "name": "test",
    "properties": {
        "runtimeState": "Started",
        "pipelines": [
            {
                "pipelineReference": {
                    "referenceName": "ForEachMetadata",
                    "type": "PipelineReference"
                }
            }
        ],
        "type": "ScheduleTrigger",
        "typeProperties": {
            "recurrence": {
                "frequency": "Minute",
                "interval": 1,
                "startTime": "2019-02-25T16:23:00.000Z",
                "timeZone": "UTC",
                "schedule": {
                    "minutes": [
                        0,
                        30
                    ],
                    "hours": [
                        10,
                        11
                    ],
                    "weekDays": [
                        "monday",
                        "tuesday",
                        "wednesday",
                        "thursday",
                        "friday"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

5. As soon as it's published I get that the trigger failes:
   [image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please revisit the JSON and update

```
"frequency": "Minute",
```

with

```
"frequency": "Week",
```

and that should help .

Comment: I was struggling with the error message ` ErrorMessage=The recurrence schedule of trigger has an invalid recurrence frequency 'Hour'.` and found this post which resolves the issue. In order to limit the range of hourly executions, the frequency needs to be set to Weekly with an interval of 1. Hours are then specified and week days.